# C# LINQ Select Only Items with Unique Properties

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to get target all items that have a unique value for a string property using LINQ lambda.

For example:

```
Col_1    Col_2
1        "AAA"
2        "BBB"
3        "AAA"
4        "CCC"
```

Returns:

```
Col_1    Col_2
2        "BBB"
4        "CCC"
```

Not sure how to achieve this without iterating over the list twice.

Answer (score 4):

```
q.GroupBy(x => x.Col_2).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).SelectMany(g => g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a group by:

```
var result= collection.GroupBy(e=>e.Col_2).Where(g=>g.Count()==1).SelectMany(g=>g);
```

[`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you to flatten the resulted groups of one element in one sequence.